# Binding keyboard shortcuts to an outlook toolbar button/custom macro?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm using outlook 2007 and wanted to know if there is an option to bind keyboard shortcuts to outlook toolbar buttons?

Outlook 2010 has the special office 'strip' which allows you to place specific custom buttons with automatic shortcuts (Alt+1, Alt+2 ...) - is there something like that in Outlook 2007?

**Edit:** As I already answered my question (in some way) - I realized that I might not have explained the problem accurately - What I needed was to be able to bind keyboard shortcuts to my custom macros. I assumed the only way to do it is by adding them as toolbar buttons - but that is not a requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem:

1. Add the custom buttons to the `menu bar` instead of the `tool bar`
2. Give it a name with an accelerator, e.g.: `&1. Move to ....`
3. Define the button to display `Image and Text` so I'll have my Icon and the Accelerator displayed.

Below is the example of what I did

[image: Example]

Now the `Alt+1` accelerator invokes the `Expire in 30 days` operation.

Would appreciate any other solution as well - this feels like a workaround ...

Comment: I'm having the same question - did you find a better solution? Cluttering the menu bar with useful commands is really an ugly workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately the best solution was to upgrade to outlook 2010. It provides better flexibility for manipulating the toolbar. I did not attempt to bind shortcuts to activities not in the toolbar.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Upgrade to Outlook 2010 is not an option at the moment - I'm in a corporate environment. :-|